# Accessing both props and navigation in js-react native

Tags: javascript, react-props

i am trying to put a prop and {navigation, route} in the same function but it won't work. I even tried to declare a variable instead of prop but that wouldn't work either. The code is shown below. Can sb please tell me what am I doing wrong.

```
function CustomDrawerContent(props, {navigation, route}) {
  //const { navigation } = props;
  const onSignOut = props.onSignOut ;
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
    <View>
    <Text> MENU </Text>
    </View>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem
        label="Logout"
        onPress={onSignOut}
      />
      <DrawerItem
        icon={(props) => <Ionicons name="ios-exit" {...props} />}
        label="close drawer"
        onPress={() => navigation.closeDrawer()}
      />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}
```

Comment: how are you passing navigation to CustomDrawerContent?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to pass ````props`as parameter of your component or to destructure the`props``` object inside, but not to do both at the same time.
Did you try to do this ? Juts destructuring the props object with the properties you need :

```
function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  const { navigation, route, onSignOut } = props;
```